# Mostrar variável no src do script

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Preciso passar dois parâmetros via `url` e criar uma função JS receber esses parâmetros e colocá-los no source de um script.

Segue o que já tenho.

Link com os parametros: `<a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/cotacao?id=17&fonte=Verdana">Dólar</a>`

Função para pegar os parâmetros:

```
<script>
                    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
                    var items = url.split("&");
                    var array = {
                      'id' : items[0],
                      'fonte' : items[1]
                    }
                    var id = array.id;
                    var fonte = array.fonte;
                    //alert(id);
                    //alert(fonte);
                </script>
```

Script onde deve vir as variáveis id e fonte:

```
<!-- Widgets Notícias Agrícolas - www.noticiasagricolas.com.br/widgets -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.noticiasagricolas.com.br/widget/cotacoes.js.php?ID&FONTE&tamanho=10pt&largura=500px&cortexto=333333&corcabecalho=B2C3C6&corlinha=DCE7E9&imagem=true&output=js"></script>
```

Erro retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link da imagem: [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n5SR.png)

Comment: Não seria melhor você declarar essas variáveis como globais ou colocar em um objeto de configuração?

Comment: Olá André, da maneira que fiz eu consigo pegar os valores, mas não consigo inserir as variaveis no src do script. O resultado dos alerts que estao comentados sao: alert(id) -> id=17 e alert(fonte) -> fonte=Verdana... exatamente o que preciso colocar nos lugares de ID e FONTES no src. Desculpe a ignorancia, sou nova em programação.

Comment: Entendi. Você _tem_ que fazer isso com javascript ou pode usar PHP pra imprimir esses valores ali no `src`?

Comment: @FláviaAmaral quando resolver uma pergunta que você criou, crie uma resposta e marque-a como aceite. Aqui não colocamos resolvido na pergunta nem a solução. É um site de perguntas e respostas. Ainda bem que resolveu seu problema :)

Comment: Oi Jorge, obrigada pelo feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução: Troquei toda a função por um echo, adicionando $_GET onde desejo.

```
 <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.noticiasagricolas.com.br/widget/cotacoes.js.php?id=".$_GET['id']‌​."&tamanho=12pt&cortexto=333333&corcabecalho=B2C3C6&corlinha=DCE7E9&imagem=true&o‌​utput=js'></scrit>"; ?>
```